# Dynamic binding in C++ on copied object

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

I have a problem in virtual function:
Here is some code as an example:

```
class A
   {
      public : virtual  void print(void)
           {
              cout<< "A::print()"<<endl;
           }
    };
 class B : public A
    {
      public : virtual void print(void)
           {
               cout<<"B::print()"<<endl;
           }
    };
 class C : public A
    {
      public : void print(void)
            {
               cout<<"C::print()"<<endl;
            }
     };
  int main(void)
     {
         A a,*pa,*pb,*pc;
         B b;
         C c;
         pa=&a;
         pb=&b;
         pc=&c;

         pa->print();
         pb->print();
         pc->print();

         a=b;
         a.print();
         return 0;
       }
```

the result:
             A::print()
             B::print()
             C::print()
             A::print()

I know it's a Polymorphism ,and know have a table called virtual-function-table,but I don't know how it is to achieve,And

```
   a=b;
   a.print();
```

the result is: A::print() not B::print(),why it hasn't polymorphism.
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=b;
a.print();
```

It will print `A::print()` because `a=b` causes object-slicing, which means `a` gets only the *a-subobject* of `b`. Read this :

- [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) .

Note that runtime-polymorphism can be achieved **only** through *pointer* and *reference* types. In the above code, `a` is neither *pointer*, nor *reference* type:

```
A * ptr = &b; //syntax : * on LHS, & on RHS
A & ref =  b; //syntax : & on LHS, that is it!

ptr->print(); //will call B::print() (which you've already seen)
ref.print();  //will call B::print() (which you've not seen yet)
```

Answer (score 5):

The object `a` is still of *type* `A`. The assignment only copies data from `b`, it doesn't make `a` a `B` object.

This is called [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Answer (score 1):

Because `a` is not a *pointer*. It is an instance of `A`, and the assignment `a=b;` *copies* the instance of `b` to `a`. But the function call is on an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a = b;` you `b` object is sliced i.e. only the `A` part of it gets copied. Polymorphism only works through pointers and references. Search "object slicing" to learn about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about virtual method table please see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). But in general case the table keeps the information methods' addresses. So, class A in the table will have one record says that method *print* is in address X. When you do *pa=&b* class B simply replace the table to its one in such a way that address of method *print* will point to address Y.

But when you do *a=b* you copy object. In this case polymorphism doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After a call to *any* member function on a object of type `A`, you still have `A` object (except an explicit destructor call, which leaves nothing at all).

```
 a = b;
```

The assignment of a class instance is just a call to a particular member function called "`operator=`". There is nothing special with "`operator=`" here, except its name is standard. You could use another name for assignment:

```
a = b;
// you could as well write:
a.assign(b);
// (if such member was defined)
```

Just as you could write `add(a,b)` instead of `a+b`, but `a+b` is more readable.

An explicit call to a function never changes the type of the variable it is called on:

```
A a;
foo(a);
// a is still a A
a.bar();
// a is still a A
```

The declared type of `a` is `A`, and cannot be changed to something else: this is an invariant of `a`.

This is also true for pointers: **a variable of type pointer to `A` will always have the type pointer to `A`**:

```
void foo (A*&);
A *bar();

A a;
A *p = &a;
foo (p); // might change p
// a still has type: pointer to A
p = bar();
// a still has type: pointer to A
```

But `p` might point to an object of type `B`, so, at runtime, the dynamic type of `*p` will be `B`; but **the dynamic type of `p` is always `A*`**.